# MongoDB c# Driver - Perform a LINQ "Any" in a Serialized Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I have a document type with some attributes, one of which is a Dictionary< string, string >.

Serialization and *De-serealization* seem to work fine (I can search, perform CRUD operations, etc.). The problem is that I'm trying to write a method to find all the objects of that type where the dictionary contains a specific value (id) among its Keys.

**Attempted Query:**

```
var objectCollection = db.GetCollection<MyClass>("MyClass");

var query = Query<MyClass>.Where(m => m.MyDictionary.Any(k => k.Key == id));
```

**The Class:**

```
public class MyClass
{

    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    [BsonElement("Dictionary")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> MyDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

...but I get this Exception while building the query:

```
Any requires that the serializer specified for Dictionary support items by implementing 
MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonArraySerializer and returning a non-null result. 
MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DictionarySerializer`2[System.String,System.String] 
is the current serializer.
```

I suspect the problem is related to the fact that the c# driver's default serializer doesn't support this. Is there a workaround?

I've also tried to perform a "Contains" for the `id` string on the `Dictionary.Keys` collection, but that gives a `NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: m.Dictionary.Keys.`

Comment: Maybe you could try converting the m.MyDictionary.Keys to a list first before putting into the linq?

var listOfKeys = m.Dictionary.Keys.ToList();

Comment: Nope: `NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: Enumerable.ToList<String>(m.Dictionary.Keys).` too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out on my own...

Added an annotation in `MyClass` to specify how I want the Dictionary to be serialized ([read about DictionarySerializationOptions here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/) for more info).

```
[BsonElement("Dictionary")]
[BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)] // Added This!
public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get; set; }
```

This serializes the Dictionary as an array of Documents, each containing a "k" (key) and "v" (value).

Then I changed my query to:

```
var query = Query.ElemMatch("Dictionary", Query.EQ("k", id));
```

This searches entries in my collection in which the Dictionary contains `id` as one of its keys.

Other relevant links:

- [MongoDB and C# Dictionary Serialisation, Part 1 – The Problem](http://www.danharman.net/2011/09/14/mongodb-and-c-dictionary-serialisation-part-1-the-problem/#comments)
- [How to query a sub document collection using MongoDB and C# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467825/how-to-query-a-sub-document-collection-using-mongodb-and-c-sharp-driver?rq=1)