# How can I search a collection of several list<T> with queries?

Tags: c#, list, mongodb, serialization

I am new to MongoDb so I just played around with it.

Right now I have created a `MongoDbCollection<MyDocument>` which stores a lot of `MyDocuments`. `MyDocument` holds many different parameters like `ID`, `Name`, `Birthdate`, `xData`, ...

```
class MyDocument
{
    public MyDocument() { }

    public ObjectID Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Birthdate { get; set; }
    public BsonDocument[] xData { get; set; } // just additional data
}
```

If I query the `MongoDbCollection` for documents...

```
MongoCursor elements = collection.Find(Query.And(MyQueryInput));
```

for example: a query which is looking for name "Peter". I'll get a list with all elements where 'name' equals "peter". It also returns the 'name' field from the "xData" `BsonDocument`. So far so good everything works as wanted.

Now I want to create a `MongoDbCollection<List<MyDocument>>`, so its a collection of lists which hold `MyDocuments`. Thats why I defined a new class which holds the `MongoID` and a `List`:

```
class MyMongoList
{
    public MyMongoList() { }

    public ObjectID Id() { get; set; }
    public List<MyDocument> list { get; set; }
}
```

I can add `MyDocuments` to the list and lists to the collection, but if I loop through nothing happens.

```
MongoCursor elements = collection.Find(Query.And(MyQueryInput));
foreach(MyMongoList<MyDocument> list in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine("something"); // nothing happends here
}
```

I am wondering why "elements" is empty.

**[Question]** Is it possible to query all lists like above?

**[Question]** Do I have to add something to the MyMongoList class that MongoDb can search in c#Lists?

At the moment, I do not know what's wrong. I have the feeling that it has to do with MongoDb [Serialization](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/) but until now I did not find a way to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my mistakes. I just have to use the Query.ElemMatch() method. An example was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467825/how-to-query-a-sub-document-collection-using-mongodb-and-c-sharp-driver).

to query a list I used the following code:

```
MongoCursor elements = collection.Find(Query.ElemMatch("list",MyQueryInput));
```

Now MongoDB puts all lists from the collection, which possess at least 1 MyDokument matching the criterion, into elements.